# SQL reporting services datasource not visible in designer. Why? and How do I fix it?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, datasource, report

So Im maintaining some reports in a VS2005 .NET project. The reports use object classes from a business layer as datasets but they arent listen in the menu in the report designer. I have no clue why not but it makes dealing with them a pain. To add or manipulate the datasets I am forced to use notepad to edit the nodes to add fields and whatnot. We are using that microsoft report viewer tool instead of a reports server (not that that has anything to do with it). But anyway, Why cant I see the datasets in the designer tool. Im guessing maybe the person who initialy developed the reports might have used a newer version of visual studio and then just added them to the TFS project. I get the benefits of business layer objects and whatnot in the appcode but im ready to start just referencing the DB Procs directly from the reports and chop the current datasouces out of the report code. BUT... finding a way to at least view them from within vs2005 would be awesome for me actually meeting some of these deadlines.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has happened to me when a data-source named/referenced in the datasets doesn't exist.  (I did a find and replace in the code and I forgot that the text was also included in the name of my primary data-source for the report, so it changed the name referenced in all of those datasets.... It didn't change the name of the actual data-source because I hadn't highlighted it in my find/replace selection)....

```
<DataSet Name="Facility">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="facility_id">
      <DataField>Facility_ID</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Guid</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="facName">
      <DataField>facName</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>Database</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>select distinct name facName, Facility_ID<br>from Location<br>where<br>Facility_ID = Location.FacilityId and<br>facility_ID = upper(@fac)<br></CommandText>
    <QueryParameters>
      <QueryParameter Name="@fac">
        <Value>=Parameters!fac.Value</Value>
        <rd:UserDefined>true</rd:UserDefined>
      </QueryParameter>
    </QueryParameters>
    <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
  </Query>
</DataSet>
```

---

```
<DataSourceName>Database</DataSourceName>
```

"Database" needs to be a data-source that actually exists, meaning... you see it in design view?  If this doesn't help please give some more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it turns out that the guys whoever developed the reports did it in a separate project where the objects and reports were in the same namespace. But it looks like when he added them to the solution he added the reports to the webproject and the objects to the business layer project so I can see how the the designer can not see the objects. Unfortunately im having another trouble now where i cant open an rdlc file(in the designer) in my solution without visual studio crashing. I am able to modify the files outside of the solution and was able to fulfill my change requests.

Comment: After I spend some time making some app changes hopefully ill have time and money to do some configuration management and get those reports in a more manageable state. Thanks so much for your input though. That definitely sounds like the problem. The reports work though, so i think its just a namespace issue more then the datasets not existing. Hopefully ill get a chance to look into it before i forget.

Comment: oh... and your penguin doesn't look very gloomy